# Strange error with Keras and Spyder

Tags: python, keras, protobuf-net, spyder

I'm using Spyder to do some small projects with Keras, and every now and then (I haven't pinned down what it is in the code that makes it appear) I get this message:

```
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py", line 1771, in <module>
    __module__ = 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2'

TypeError: A Message class can only inherit from Message
```

Weirdly, this exception is not raised if I execute the program outside of Spyder, using the terminal. I've looked around and I have found no one who has encountered this error while using Keras.

Restarting Spyder makes it go away, but it's frustrating. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause: interrupting the execution before Keras fully loads.

As said before restarting Spyder (or just the console) solves it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Spyder, which happened when it was trying to reload modules that were already loaded. I solved it by disabling the UMR (User Module Reloader) option in "preferences -> python interpreter" .

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Sypder works or run your script using console only.
Don't forget to use at the top:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport import requests
```