# A Message class can only inherit from Message - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I got this error when I implemented from google.cloud import storage.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/apps/repo/oktested/oktested-backend/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ok_app import app as application
  File "./ok_app/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from google.cloud.storage.batch import Batch
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/batch.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.cloud import _helpers
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 33, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import duration_pb2
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/duration_pb2.py", line 69, in <module>
    '__module__' : 'google.protobuf.duration_pb2'
TypeError: A Message class can only inherit from Message
unable to load app 1 (mountpoint='oktested') (callable not found or import error)
```

The code is:

```
from google.cloud import storage
creds = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('s-creds.json')
def uploadProfilePic(id, image_name, image):        
        filename = id + '__' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '__' + image_name
        dest_dir = app.config['S3_DIR'] + app.config['PROFILE_PIC_PATH']
        filepath = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        image_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', image)
        img_data = base64.b64decode(image_data)
        try:
            if 'jpeg' in filename:
                image_type = "image/jpeg"
            elif 'png' in filename:
                image_type = "image/png"
            elif 'jpg' in filename:
                image_type = "image/jpg"
            # s3.Bucket(app.config['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).put_object(Key=filepath, Body=img_data, ACL=app.config['S3_ACL'], ContentType ='image/jpeg', CacheControl=app.config['S3_CACHE_CONTROL'])
            bucket = creds.bucket(app.config['GCP_BUCKET_NAME'])
            blob = bucket.blob(filepath)
            blob.upload_from_string(img_data, content_type=image_type)
            app.logger.debug("User::uploadProfilePic::SuccessfullyUploaded::{}".format(filepath))
            return filepath
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error("User::uploadProfilePic:: {}". format(e))
            return ''
```

I run the code on server using uwsgi. I get this error even after Restarting the service. Please help.

Comment: Try writing the output as a code block so it will be easier to read, and adding some of your code would be useful.

Comment: Like theFrok said, we need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange error with Keras and Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894208/strange-error-with-keras-and-spyder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, I am now calling the google cloud methods only where I need it, not during the app initialization.